# Use SqlFunctions.IsNumeric() where trailing spaces are present?

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, sqlclient

I have a simple LINQ-to-Entities query as below:

```
 var BillingNumbers = from o in dbcontext.Orders
                      where SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(o.BillingNumber) == 1
                      select o.BillingNumber;
```

This query works most of the time. Recently, however, I encountered a situation where the BillingNumber was indeed numeric, but had some trailing spaces. This query completely missed those values.

If `SqlFunctions.IsNumeric()` can't ignore the trailing spaces, what are the alternatives?

.Net 4/EF4/VS2010

Comment: Trim them before, I suppose... perhaps a view (or *fix the data* ;-)? Or pull them into C# and check them locally? Or can use a custom UDF with linq-to-entities? (There be other beasties lurking in `IsNumeric`.)

Comment: What's your definition of "numeric"? Does `.0` count? How about `$12,345`? Or `+12.345e-12`?

Comment: @Gabe Numeric in this case is strictly a 6 digit whole number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
where SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(o.BillingNumber.Trim()) == 1
```

It translates to

```
WHERE (ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(RTRIM([Extent1].[BillingNumber])))) > 0
```

Be aware of the fact that this way of querying is not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), so if you can narrow down your orders in any other way before this comparison, make sure you do it!

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't like the idea of storing numbers in strings, since you are only looking for 6-digit strings, you can do something like this:

```
SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%", o.BillingNumber) > 0
```

Although it would give you false positives for numbers with things other than spaces, but you can adjust for that.